# Add a number to the beginning of a string in particular locations

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this string:

`abc,12345,abc,abc,abc,abc,12345,98765443,xyz,zyx,123`

What can I use to add a `0` to the beginning of each number in this string? So how can I turn that string into something like:

`abc,012345,abc,abc,abc,abc,012345,098765443,xyz,zyx,0123`

I've tried playing around with Regex but I'm unsure how I can use that effectively to yield the result I want. I need it to match with a string of numbers rather than a positive integer, but with only numbers in the string, so not something like:

`1234abc567` into `01234abc567` as it has letters in it. Each value is always separated by a comma.

Comment: `','.join(['0' + x if x.isdigit() else x for x in s.split(',')])
'abc,012345,abc,abc,abc,abc,012345,098765443,xyz,zyx,0123'`

Comment: @mic4ael: You should post a proper answer! Don't let the regex guys win all the points for something that can be easily done without regex. :) You will need to add a little bit of text, since code-only answers are generally not well-received on SO.

Comment: @PM2Ring ya, I know how to do this in a non-regex way but using regex is so simple than splitting, checking and joining.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.sub`,

```
re.sub(r'(^|,)(\d)', r'\g<1>0\2', s)
```

or

```
re.sub(r'(^|,)(?=\d)', r'\g<1>0', s)
```

or

```
re.sub(r'\b(\d)', r'0\1', s)
```

Comment: I got a `sre_constants.error: invalid group reference` error on the first 2 but the 3rd one worked, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\b)(\d+)(?=\b)', r'\g<1>0', str)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are always seperated by commas in your string, you can use basic list methods to achieve the result you want.

Let's say your string is called x

```
y=x.split(',')
x=''
for i in y:
    if i.isdigit():
        i='0'+i
    x=x+i+','
```

What this piece of code does is the following:
Splits your string into pieces depending on where you have commas and returns  a list of the pieces.
Checks if the pieces are actually numbers, and if they are a 0 is added using string concatenation. 
Finally your string is rebuilt by concatenating the pieces along with the commas.

Comment: `.isdigit()` is a standard method of `str` objects... which is why the syntax you're using works. :) BTW, `x += i +','` is slightly better than `x=x+i+','`, although using `.join`, as in mic4ael's comment, is even better, especially for large strings.

Comment: Yeah, i probably confused it with something else, thanks for pointing that out